# Match last digit of string

Tags: regex

I haven't found what I am looking for, but I am trying to match the last digit of strings. For example, I want to pull out only those that end in the number 9 from the data below. How can this be done in regex? I'm just beginning to play around with it, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
abc12997654
efg12456789
dkj98765433
kij12444449
yur123ert97
```

output:

```
efg12456789
kij12444449
```

Comment: To better answer this, it would be helpful to know what language you are using, as the syntax for RegEx's varies depending.

Comment: you have "words" in a string, and want to match the whole word only if it ends with 9, or are those distinct strings?

Comment: specify your input and desired output in coding format please

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to do that (of course there are alternatives) is as follows:

It matches the words only ending with a digit 9.

```
/(\w+9\b)/g
```

Answer (score 2):

`(.*9$)` is a simpler regex that will give you your output!

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2iZ5l6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use word boundaries to assert a correct match occurs.

**regex:** `\b\w+9\b`

https://regex101.com/r/hAA0pC/1

Answer (score 1):

```
\b\w+9\b
```

> **\b** matches a non word character, in this case start and end of the string.

---

> **\w** matches a alpha-numeric or _ character, + grabs one or more matching characters.